# App Inventor Integrating AirTurn BT-105 Pedal as a control input

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using App Inventor to communicate with 2 devices via bluetooth.

I am trying to use the AirTurn BT-105 Pedal to control a separate bluetooth device that is connected to my phone. The pedal connects automatically to my phone and has an input control on my phone.

I am unable to read the input in the app I am creating, as the pedal is not assigned as "Client 1" "Client 2" or "Server". How can I access the data the pedal sends to my phone? Is there a way to assign a connected bluetooth device to client or server?

Answer (score 0):

The AirTurn BT-105 is basically a Bluetooth HID keyboard device sending PageUp/Dn, Left/Right, Up/Down key presses. I don't know anything about the App Inventor, but if it is referring to "client" and "server" assignments, that may be expecting a (SPP) Serial Port Profile connection, instead of HID connection.